# Ising 1D model, correlation function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, ising-model

Can someone please help me with this...

I need to show that the expression for a 1D chain of fermions $F(r)=\langle(c_j^\dagger -c_j)(c_{j+r}^\dagger+c_{j+r})\rangle$ can be expressed as: $F(r)=-\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{i[q r+2\phi_q]}\space\tanh(\beta \epsilon(q)/2)$ $(q=\frac{2\pi}{L} k)$ if a fourier transformation of the creation and anihilation operators $c_j=\frac{e^{-i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_k e^{i \frac{2\pi}{L} k j}d_k $, followed by a Bogoliubov transformation $d_k=\cos{\phi_k}b_k-\sin{\phi_k}b_{-k}^\dagger $ is made.

Where $\phi_k=-\phi_{-k},\space H=\sum_k\epsilon(k)b_k^\dagger b_k,$ $(\frac{2\pi}{L}k)$ runs in L steps in the range  $-\pi$ to $\pi$. For fermions $\langle b_k^\dagger b_k\rangle=(exp(\beta\space\epsilon(k))+1)^{-1}$. $\sum_k\rightarrow L\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq}{2\pi}$

I know that for the expectation value I have to calculate $\langle A \rangle=\frac{tr(e^{-\beta H}A)}{Z}$.
I first multiply to get $F(r)=\langle(c_j^\dagger c_{j+r}^\dagger+c_j^\dagger c_{j+r}-c_j c_{j+r}^\dagger-c_j c_{j+r})\rangle$. I then only keep $\langle(c_j^\dagger c_{j+r}-c_j c_{j+r}^\dagger\rangle)$. Then I get $c_j c_{j+r}^\dagger=\frac{1}{L}\sum_k e^{-\frac{2\pi}{L}k \space r}d_k d_k^\dagger$ and $c_j^\dagger c_{j+r}=\frac{1}{L}\sum_ke^{\frac{2\pi}{L}k\space r}d_k^\dagger d_k$, while only keeping the diagonal terms. I then do the Bogoliubov transformation but at the end can't show that $F(r)$ can be expressed as $F(r)=-\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{i[q r+2\phi_q]}\space\tanh(\beta \epsilon(q)/2)$ $(q=\frac{2\pi}{L} k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your calculations. You can verify that
$$
\left< d_k d_{-k} \right> \neq 0
$$
Hence
$$
\left< c_j c_{j+r} \right> \neq 0.
$$

Comment: Actually I have now been able to solve this, thanks!

Comment: It's one of the key features of the Bogolubov transformation that _anomalous_ expectations have non-zero values.